# Is this usage of "know to be" correct — "They want to eat food they know to be good for them"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, meaning-in-context, infinitives

In the following sentence, is the construction *know* + *to* + *infinitive* grammatical?

> They want to eat food they know to be good for them.

The dictionary says that "know to do something" is a correct construction. But can it be used in the above example?

If correct, is the meaning of the sentence similar/identical to "They want to eat food they know is good for them"? If not, what's the difference? If yes, how do they sound to a native speaker? To me as a non-native speaker, the "...know is good..." one sounds OK, but the "...know to be good..." one is sort of clumsy.

Answer (score 4):

*They want to eat food they know to be good for them* is grammatical and it means the same as *They want to eat food they know is good for them*. Most native speakers would have no difficulty in understanding either and neither sounds particularly odd, but the first is possibly slightly more formal.

Answer (score 1):

Either sentence is ok.  The point will be made with either choice.  Personally, I prefer the first one.  Both sentences could be improved by adding "which" between the clauses.

```
They want to eat food which they know to be good for them.
```

or

```
They want to eat food which they know is good for them.
```

Again, both will communicate the same idea.

Comment: Or "that" instead of "which."